# Can not load on click

Tags: jquery, load, onclick

I am trying to get the below script to run but I can't, any suggestions?
The point is I am trying to call external content from other pages. When i write it individually it is okay, but when I tried to load it from a list or by click, it doesn't work as expected

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="1/1.html">text 1</a>
    <a href="1/2.html">text 1</a>
</div>  

<b>see the text:</b>
<ol id="new-nav"></ol>

<script>
    $("#test").click(function () {
        $("#new-nav").load("href");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Instead of passing "href" to load` which is not a valid resource `pass the href of link being clicked`, I also changed the selector to bind click with anchor. Putting in $(document).ready will ensure the availabilty of dom Element before use, It safe to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         

    $("#test a").click(function (e) {

        // Stop the link from changing the page
        //e.preventDefault();

        // Your jQuery code.

        $("#new-nav").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @musefan just changed the selector

Comment: You should also prevent the default action of the anchor links. `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: You  Are Just Amazing Thank u a lot. I read about load in the http://docs.jquery.com/Events/load but i couldn't figure it out thanks  jq Gurus !!

Comment: You want to change anchor "a" with li?

Comment: Yes Sorry to bother u again , yes can i do that? - The script works fine now but i am trying to use the "li" from <?php include 'Menu/Side-menu.html.php'; ?> to load to my current page , is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can do with li, You can put anchor tag in li as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19473/discussion-between-lefteris-livanos-and-adil)

Answer (score -1):

Put your code as I show you below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // Your jQuery code.
});
```

You have to put document.ready because jQuery code always run after documents are completely loaded, or DOM object are compltely loaded...

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you don't intend to provide an answer, then this should only be a comment. For now, you get a down vote... delete or add an answer